# Many-to-Many relationship in WPF with EF and SQLite

Tags: c#, wpf, sqlite

I'm following [this](http://www.bricelam.net/2012/10/entity-framework-on-sqlite.html) tutorial in order to implement a local database (using SQLite) for my WPF application.

Everything works as it should, although I have a logical problem I don't know how to solve using this approach. I'll simplify it below.

Database-wise, I have 2 tables (A,B) which share a many-to-many relationship, and thus require a JOIN table as well (ABJoin).

In my actual code however, I'd like to use only 2 models: A and B, which each having a list of the other type. Like this:

```
public class A {
    // ...fields
    List<B> bList;
}

public class B {
    // ...fields
    List<A> aList;
}
```

**How can it be implemented in EF+SQLite?**

Searching online, I have found some solutions, but nothing that applies to SQLite, so I was not sure how they'd work.

Comment: It is not concerned to WPF

Comment: you should use another table or entity for the many to many relationship.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### [Configure Many-to-Many Relationships in Code-First](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-many-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx)

Comment: Thanks @KostasT! Apparently this is the simplest answer of all, works like charm, even with SQLite :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using many to many join table then your each class should have a list of the join table.

It cannot work the way you are thinking.

Comment: The join table works as a bridge between two entities having many to many relationship. And if you are using entity framework, then you will having navigation properties as follows to reach from A to B.

A.AB.B and
B.AB.A

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that it is a good idea not to have a third entity?

Lets say your two entities were `DepartmentStore` and `Product`, a typical example for an n:n relationship. A department store can sell many products and a product may be available in many departments stores. This results in a third entity which connects the two above, in the example above this would something like `ProductAvailability`.
If you think about it more careful, then you might realize that the new connecting entity might have properties of its own. In my example this might be `NumberOfProducts`, will states the available quantity of a product in a certain department store.

In my experience, it is quite common for the connecting entity to have a real value that goes beyond just connecting two other entities.

I also took a look at you example which it about `Album` and `Artist` entities.
Do you want to make a data model where an `Album` can be created by more than one `Artist`?

Answer (score 0):

Entity Framework doesn't have automatic many-to-many mapping.
Instead of this, you can map A and B to intermediate table as one-to-many.

If you are not obliged to use only EF, I suggest to try NHibernate ORM instead.
It has convenient many-to-many mapping and generally more powerful.